# How to list all metadata of a sobject through salesforce tooling api by SOAP call?

Tags: tooling-api, list-metadata

I am trying to fetch metadata related to an sobject by SOAP call through Tooling API. For example, I am trying to fetch all the Apex Pages available in my org but unable to find any relevant API in SOAP implementation.
By Metadata API, we have listMetadata api available which uses sobject name as parameter and returns all the available metadata of passed sobject.
Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to get metadata for an sObject or a list of Apex Pages.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get metdata for an SObject(ApexPages, ApexClasses etc.) by SOAP API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for a list of ApexPages or metadata around an sObject as your question is not clear.

The documentation around [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm) is pretty specific. This would be the call for the ApexPages:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexpage.htm

> Represents the saved copy
>   of an Apex page. ApexPage uses the cached    version of the class
>   unless one is unavailable.  Available from API version 28.0 or 
>   later.
>   
>         To edit, save, or compile Apex
>   pages, use ApexPageMember.
>   
>     
>   
>      Supported SOAP API
>   Calls
>
> ```
>    <p class="p"><samp class="codeph nolang">create()</samp>,&nbsp;<samp class="codeph
> ```
>
> nolang">delete(), describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve(), update(), upsert()
>   
>     
>   
>      Supported REST API HTTP
>       Methods
>
> ```
>    <p class="p"><samp class="codeph nolang">Query</samp>, <samp class="codeph nolang">GET</samp>, <samp class="codeph
> ```
>
> nolang">POST, PATCH, DELETE
>   
>     
>   
>      Usage
>
> ```
>    <p class="p">To retrieve information about a Visualforce page, create an ApexPage object
> that references it. For example code, see <a class="xref" href="atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_soap_overview.htm">SOAP
> ```
>
> Calls.
>   
>      To edit, save, or compile Visualforce pages, use ApexPageMember.

Click through the links in the document to get to your specific answers

Comment: I have to use SOAP call from java to fetch the list of all apex pages available in the Org. Below URL describes all the available soap calls by tooling api
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_soap_overview.htm 
so, From these api calls how can I find all the available pages or classes or someother sobject.